# Необходимо получить токен python

Tags: python, token, csrf

При обращении к сайту по url необходимо получить csrf-token. Нашёл его в заголовке HTML, но как вытащить его в переменную для дальнейшей авторизации?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  

  <meta name="_csrf" content="ccf0b6d7-4235-41ce-822d-9ac010118b67" /> #Здесь токен

  <meta name="_csrf_header" content="X-CSRF-TOKEN" />

  <meta name="_csrf_parameter" content="_csrf" />

  

    <meta name="page-id" content="login-page" />

    <title>
```

Comment: `response = requests.get(url)` для начала и вот уже у `response` либо в `headers` либо в `cookies` и ищите ваш токен, а вот оттуда уже через `get`. З.Ы. Вообще не понятно какое отношение представленный код имеет к тэгу `python`

Answer (score 0):

никакого питон-кода вы не выложили, поэтому какой-то пример из головы. Можно токен так вытащить:

```
import re
html="""<!DOCTYPE html>
   ...
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="_csrf" content="ccf0b6d7-4235-41ce-822d-9ac010118b67" /> #Здесь токен
  <meta name="_csrf_header" content="X-CSRF-TOKEN" />
  <meta name="_csrf_parameter" content="_csrf" />
  <meta name="page-id" content="login-page" />
  ...
  """
regex=r"name=\"_csrf\" content=\"([^\"]+)\""
ans = re.search(regex,html)
if ans:
    print(ans[1])#вывод токена
```